# "Open With" ...running application option?

Tags: finder

*This may have been asked before but I couldn't find any reference to it.*

So Control-Click on a file brings up the context menu with "Open", "Open With.." and a number of other options. I often want to open a text based file in something other than the default application – for example, opening an `mxml` (Flex) file in BBEdit. The default application for that is Flash Builder and I don't want to change the default.

Is there some kind of extension or service I can add to have an "Open with Running Application...(list of open applications)"?

Or if not that, a way a user (me!) can register an app to open certain file types, so for example, BBEdit is listed as an option for `mxml` but is not the default?

Comment: I just realised that in the specific case of BBEdit you should already have "Open File in BBEdit" within the "Services" part of the context menu (at least I do)

Comment: @Asmus - yes, I just found that too as I was setting up a Service in Automator. Who knew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use automator. It's simple: create a new service with preferences (what items in which program to open). That's all - on right click menu there will be a new rule - "open in ...".

Answer (score 2):

You could just drag the file onto the App icon in the Dock… *[which is very difficult to take a screenshot of…]*

[image]

*[after comments…]*
Alternatively, you could…

- drag the file onto the app switcher - the one you bring up by pressing  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>

or

- use [DragThing](http://www.dragthing.com/english/about.html) which has been a kind of substitute Dock since long before the Dock existed.

Comment: This should be the answer _[not only for taking a screenshot whilst dragging chicken paprika onto the dock]_! Alternatively, you could drag the file onto the app switcher (the one you bring up by pressing cmd+tab).

Comment: Nice. That one's new to me. I actually have always used [DragThing](http://www.dragthing.com/english/about.html) (since v1.0 in 1995 :-o ) so I automatically drag to that, out of habit.

Comment: I do this but I have my dock on the side and on a double monitor system, it is very awkward to drag a Finder item to the dock using a trackpad.

Comment: Then go with @Asmus alternative, which I shall sneakily ;) add to the answer

Answer (score 0):

One way (which for just this is overkill but it has other benefits) is to use [PathFinder](http://www.cocoatech.com/pathfinder/) as a replacement for Finder.

Its Open With... menu has submenus

- Applications - listing all apps it can find e.g. in /Applications
  ~/Applications
- Running - all running apps
- Text Editor - its copy of
  TextEdit
- List of all apps that have registered for the extension